# garbage when converting from Float to BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, scala, floating-point, decimal, precision

When converting from `float` to `BigDecimal` in Java and getting some unexpected results.
Notice "garbage" digits "23841858" in the first line and up to 7th line similarly in least significant digits:

[image: float to decimal]
Above code as text:

```scala
for (w <- (1 to 70))
{
  val wp = ten.pow(w, mc)
  val onePlus :BigDecimal = one.add(one.divide(wp, mc), mc)

  val flo :Float = onePlus.floatValue()
  val flo_to_d :BigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(flo)

  println(f"""${w}: ${comp_decimals("float", onePlus, flo_to_d)}, dec=${onePlus}, flo=${flo}, flo_to_d=${flo_to_d} """)
}
```

I do not see this problem when trying to convert `double` to `BigDecimal`:

[image: double to decimal]
Above code as text:

```scala
for (w <- (1 to 70))
{
  val wp = ten.pow(w, mc)
  val onePlus :BigDecimal = one.add(one.divide(wp, mc), mc)

  val dou :Double = onePlus.doubleValue()
  val dou_to_d :BigDecimal = BigDecimal.valueOf(dou)
  
  println(f"""${w},${comp_decimals("double", onePlus, dou_to_d)}, dec=${onePlus}, dou=${dou_to_d} """ )
}
```

What is the fundamental difference in how conversion to `BigDecimal` from `float` and from `double` is done in Java?

I do understand that `float` only keeps 7 significant digits, while `double` keeps up to 15 significant digits. But this doesn't explain the odd trailing "trash" digits when converting from `float` to `BigDecimal`. FWIW, this issue only happens when converting from float to BigDecimal, and not other way around.

Btw, the below code is written in Scala, but it uses only Java native functionality when it comes to `BigDecimal` support. Java 8 / Scala 2.12. Java bug?

Comment: Please post the code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: @Sweeper added code as text